# Gravity Forms Perks - Nested Forms

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-gravity-forms

Did Gravity Forms / Perks ever complete the Nested Forms perk by any chance? The list option in GF is only useful if all fields fit in a row and are text boxes - I ideally want to inc date fields and a dropdown. If the answer is it got canned can anyone suggest an alternative please.

http://www.screencast.com/t/p7sAHutMVfG

I found this plugin - but wondered if there was a better way to do it.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/repeater-add-on-for-gravity-forms/

I have some fields e.g. name, surname, DOB, ID, Expiry date which I want to request according to the number of tickets they have requested, but all part of the same form. either enable add icon to the qty or display X number of rows according to qty.

Comment: This would be a question to ask at the [Gravity Perks](https://gravitywiz.com/available-perks/) site. WPSE isn't meant for questions about third-party plugins.

Comment: Responded to your support request, Nick. GP Nested Forms is still alive and well. :)

Comment: If of use to anyone I contacted Gravity Perks & was sent a beta version of Nested Forms which installed perfectly.